# Virtual Treeview (C++ Builder) 2 icons overlap on Windows 7 but not on XP

Tags: delphi, c++builder, virtualtreeview

I have an issue with VirtualTreeView component on Windows 7. I added a **TVirtualStringTree** and used **OnGetImageIndex** event to assign **ImageIndex** which is always in debugger non-zero value.

VirtualStringTree uses a **TImageList** with 16x16 icons as **Images** property.

On Windows XP it works properly and on Windows 7 it overlaps icon with index 0 from TImageList on top of a normal icon. I am running the same program on Windows 7 as on XP so the code is identical, but the drawing is different.

This image illustrates the issue:

[image: virtualtreeview issue]

The gray triangle icon has index of 0 and folder icon has index of 5.

Is this a bug in VirtualStringTree? Can I somehow avoid this?

I am using the latest VirtualTreeView version from repository.

Comment: Show the code of your OnGetImageIndex handler.

Comment: In that case, you may be missing the code which takes into consideration the `Kind: TVTImageKind` parameter. `ikOverlay` might be in effect. This alone would not explain your symptoms but it is an unusual use case.

Comment: I think you're right... I just looked in other piece code I do have a handler for: if (Kind == ikNormal || Kind == ikSelected) that assigns the value only if the former is true (otherwise it is -1) and that one appears to draw normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `OnGetImageIndex` event handler, pay attention to the `Kind: TVTImageKind` parameter. Assign `ImageIndex` as required (typically, this is only for `ikNormal` and `ikSelected` values), otherwise assign -1.

For example, assigning a valid image index when `Kind` has the value of `ikOverlay` will cause an overlay image to be drawn over the normal image. (Which may be related to your problem.)

Comment: Actually there is no need to assign ImageIndex explicitly because by default it is already -1 so simple check for ikNormal/ikSelected is enough.